# Evaluation of number 1 using === not the same for number 0 in cell class rules

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Trouble applying cell class rules to Ag-Grid in Angular using typescript .

I have created cell class rules as follows :

```
'style-class-1': function(params) { return params.value === 1}
'style-class-0': function(params) { return params.value === 0}
```

style-class-1 is applied when params.value is 1

style-class-0 is not applied when params value is 0

Comment: reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily

Comment: This was addressed with the following workaround : paramas.value = ''+index ; Followed by : return params.value === '0' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason this would not work is because params.value might be a string (or anything other than an int) while you're strictly comparing it to an integer. To get around this, you can do one of the following.

Compare it with a string

```
params.value === '0'
```

Or parse params.value as Integer

```
parseInt(params.value) === 0
```

Or use `==` instead of `===` which will result in javascript converting the values to the same type

```
 params.value == 0
```